# How to tell Sublime Text to include external header files in C++

Tags: c++, sublimetext

To compile and run .cpp file in Sublime Text 2, I press command + shift + B. But I don't know how to tell Sublime Text to link external .h file. When I put #include "genlib.h" and compile, I receive this error.

```
/Users/ckaj/Desktop/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'genlib.h' file not found
#include "genlib.h"
          ^
1 error generated.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "/Users/ckaj/Desktop/main.cpp" -o "/Users/ckaj/Desktop/main"]
[dir: /Users/ckaj/Desktop/]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

So, I tried putting 'genlib.h' file in the same directory to see how it works. And I get a different error as following.

```
In file included from /Users/ckaj/Desktop/main.cpp:1:
 /Users/ckaj/Desktop/genlib.h:225:1: error: expected unqualified-id
 <U+001A>
^
 1 error generated.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "/Users/ckaj/Desktop/main.cpp" -o "/Users/ckaj/Desktop/main"]
[dir: /Users/ckaj/Desktop/]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I have been searching for the answer for several hours, but to no avail. I would like to thank anyone that tries to help me fix Sublime Text 2 to work.

Comment: You need to change the build system to have additional include paths, namely one with your file.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an instruction as to how to do that? I am really new to Sublime Text. Thank you so much.

Comment: There's [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) and an [older version](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html). Beyond that, it's just adding the right options to GCC, which has nothing to do with Sublime.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I haven't fully understood the build system here. I will try to read the documentation and see how it works.

Comment: @Mick Now you've found your solution, your edit should become an answer of its own, that you will accept.

Comment: @Chnossos I am really new to stackoverflow. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Simply remove your edit and paste it into an answer. It does not matter if you answer your own question. Then, mark it as the accepted answer (click on the tick mark).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for the help. I finally read through the build document. And it seems quite simple if you understand how to compile with g++ on command line. Here is the answer.

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++ -Wall ${file} -o ./bin/${file_base_name} -I${file_path}/lib && ./bin/${file_base_name}"],
    "selector": "source.c++",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "shell": true,


    "variants": [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["g++ -Wall ${file} -o ./bin/${file_base_name} -I${file_path}/lib && open ./bin/${file_base_name}"],
            "working_dir": "${file_path}",
            "shell": true

        }
     ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @Mick's idea, this works for me (sublime text 3, ubuntu 15.10):

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++ -std=c++0x ${file_path}/*.cpp -o tmp && ./tmp"],  
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "shell": true
}
```